# How to make my VueJA/Buefy autocomplete display filtered options?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

I'm using VueJS and Beufy for an autocomplete and I thought I had this working but can't seem to get the filter correct.  When I enter the description the input box filters (try typing ar and it filters correctly) but I see no options to select.  The options are physically there as I can click on one of the options and I will see my data like this:

[image]

The second issue, presumably related is that when I do select one of these invisible options I get the following error:

> vue:634 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

I think the descriptions are blank in the autocomplete so selecting one means there is nothing toLoweCase().

What have I missed please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Product Search Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="container">
        <b-field label="Find a Product">
            <b-autocomplete
                :data="filteredDataArray"
                v-model="item_entered"
                placeholder="e.g. SKU87128398"
                :loading="isFetching"
                @select="option => selected = option">
            </b-autocomplete>
        </b-field>
      </div>

        {{selected}}


    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <!-- Full bundle -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Individual components -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/components/table"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/components/input"></script>

    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
                        return {
                            data: [],
                            selected: '',
                            isFetching: false,
                            item_entered: '',
                            initial_query: {
                                "message": "success",
                                "item_list": {
                                    "Items": [{
                                            "Description": "Marvel's Avengers",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 12   and Over",
                                            "Id": "1118498",
                                            "Type": "Product"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Description": "LEGO Harry Potter Collection",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 10 and Over",
                                            "Id": "28331719",
                                            "Type": "Product"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Description": "Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order - Standard ",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 10 and Over",
                                            "Id": "50510378",
                                            "Type": "Product"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Description": "Monster Hunter World Iceborne Master Edition",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 12 and Over",
                                            "Id": "51580152",
                                            "Type": "Product"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Description": "High Street, Bruton - More Addresses",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 18 and Over",
                                            "Id": "0AA-BA10",
                                            "Type": "Group"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    methods: {
                      getProductData: function(){

                      }
                    },
                    computed: {
                        filteredDataArray() {
                            return this.initial_query.item_list.Items.filter((option) => {
                              console.log(option.Description.toString().toLowerCase())
                              console.log(option
                                .Description
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .indexOf(this.item_entered.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                                return option
                                  .Description
                                  .toString()
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .indexOf(this.item_entered.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                            })
                        }
                    }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was harder to find than I thought but trial an error and I realised that I had missed the following field:

> field="Description"

You need to tell the autocomplete field which key from the object you want to use in the dropdown, in my case it was Description so working code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Product Search Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="container">
        <b-field label="Find a Product">
            <b-autocomplete
                :data="filteredDataArray"
                v-model="item_entered"
                placeholder="e.g. SKU87128398"
                :loading="isFetching"
                field="Description"
                @select="option => (selected = option)">
            </b-autocomplete>
        </b-field>
      </div>

        {{selected}}


    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <!-- Full bundle -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Individual components -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/components/table"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/components/input"></script>

    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
                        return {
                            data: [],
                            selected: '',
                            isFetching: false,
                            item_entered: '',
                            initial_query: {
                                "message": "success",
                                "item_list": {
                                    "Items": [{
                                            "Description": "Marvel's Avengers",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 12   and Over",
                                            "Id": "1118498",
                                            "Type": "Product"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Description": "LEGO Harry Potter Collection",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 10 and Over",
                                            "Id": "28331719",
                                            "Type": "Product"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Description": "Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order - Standard ",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 10 and Over",
                                            "Id": "50510378",
                                            "Type": "Product"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Description": "Monster Hunter World Iceborne Master Edition",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 12 and Over",
                                            "Id": "51580152",
                                            "Type": "Product"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Description": "High Street, Bruton - More Addresses",
                                            "Highlight": "PEGI Rating: Ages 18 and Over",
                                            "Id": "0AA-BA10",
                                            "Type": "Group"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    methods: {
                      getProductData: function(){

                      }
                    },
                    computed: {
                        filteredDataArray() {
                            return this.initial_query.item_list.Items.filter((option) => {
                              console.log(option.Description.toString().toLowerCase())
                              console.log(option
                                .Description
                                .toString()
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .indexOf(this.item_entered.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                                return option
                                  .Description
                                  .toString()
                                  .toLowerCase()
                                  .indexOf(this.item_entered.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                            })
                        }
                    }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```